# Custom constraints 'matches?' method never called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I tried to restricted some routing only by Ajax,
and write `routes.rb` and `lib/constraints/only_ajax_request.rb` as below.

routes.rb

```
resources :orders, except: [:destroy] do
  collection do
    post 'login_or_sign_up', to: 'orders#login_or_sign_up', constraints: OnlyAjaxRequest.new
  end
end
```

lib/constraints/only_ajax_request.rb

```
class OnlyAjaxRequest
  def matches?(request)
    request.xhr?
  end
end
```

but, this spec failed.

spec/controllers/orders_controllers_spec.rb

```
  describe 'POST #login_or_sign_up' do
    let(:user) { create(:login_user) }

    it 'only ajax' do
      post :login_or_sign_up, user: { email: user.email,
                                      password: user.password }
      expect(response.status).to eq(404)
    end
  end
```

I set breakpoint into OnlyAjaxRequest,

```
Class OnlyAjaxRequest
  def matches?(request)
    binding.pry
    request.xhr?
  end
end
```

but it was never called.

how can I set constraints to post routing?